# Tools for monitoring Xserve and Xsan

Tags: performance, mac-osx-server, performance-monitoring, xserve

I'm looking for some software (preferably commercial, supportable and easy for non-techy users to use) to monitor a number of Apple Xserve servers running OS X 10.5, and running as an Xsan controller.

Specifically I want to monitor:

- Xsan metrics including CPU, Memory, Ethernet and Fibre throughput
- XRAID performance (latency, throughput, read/write caching etc)
- Watching for specific processes possibly hanging, and after a threshold, terminate the process

I am currently evaluating Litmus 5, and I am aware Nagios can be used, but to be honest I was never impressed with Nagios and its usability.

Essentially I am looking to be able to keep an eye on the performance of the system and be able to look back on the history to compare performance when users mention any slowness/latency. Graphs are also a necessity.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Nagios for Xsan / OS X Server monitoring, but you'll have to write quite some plugins yourself (that's not as comlex, as would seem).